# Add the fillcolor to none or alpha 0, return the green background in the rendered video while using ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg-python (the wrapper for ffmpeg written in python)
Below is the sample code mentioned.

```
                     inp.filter_multi_output('split')[k]
                        .filter_('rotate', a=rotation, fillcolor='#00FF0000',  ow=f"rotw({rotation})", oh=f"roth({rotation})")
                        .filter_('scale', width=(i['width'] * Factors().factors['w_factor']), height=(i['height'] * Factors().factors['h_factor'])).filter('setsar', '1/1')
                        .setpts(f"PTS-STARTPTS+{i['showtime']}/TB")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                   inp.filter_multi_output('split')[k]
                       .filter_('scale', width=(i['width'] * Factors().factors['w_factor']), height=(i['height'] * Factors().factors['h_factor'])).filter('setsar', '1/1')
                        .filter_('rotate', a=rotation, fillcolor='#00FF0000',  ow=f"rotw({rotation})", oh=f"roth({rotation})")
                        .setpts(f"PTS-STARTPTS+{i['showtime']}/TB")
```

Just Apply the scaling before the rotation and the problem will be resolved.

Comment: use `c=black@0` or `fillcolor=black@0` for transparent background instead of `fillcolor='#00FF0000'`.

Answer (score 0):

## Transparent background in rotate filter

Use `fillcolor=none`. From the [rotate filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate):

> `fillcolor`, `c`
> Set the color used to fill the output area not covered by the rotated image. If the special value `none` is selected then no background is printed. Default value is `black`.

## Green output

If the background is green then either your output does not support alpha and/or the input had no alpha channel before giving it to the rotate filter. If the latter is the case use the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) to add an alpha channel before the rotate filter. Simplified `ffmpeg` example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "format=rgba,rotate=PI/6:fillcolor=none" output.png
```

See `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` for a list of pixel formats accepted by the format filter. Choose one with `a` in the name, such as `rgba` or `yuva420p`.

Comment: [llogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109017/llogan) I was expecting an answer from you or @Gyan. So, the issue was I am doing scaling after the rotation, what I have to do is applying the scaling filter before adding the rotation. Thank you.